# Redirecionamento HTTP PARA HTTPS com LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, htaccess, apache, domínio

Boa tarde devs, estou tendo problemas a fazer o redirecionamento HTTP para HTTPS,
tenho o seguinte conteudo no meu .HTACCESS

```
# Redireciona para o HTTPS independente do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%public/ [R=301,L]

# Adiciona www. no prefixo do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

quando acesso o site via url https:// ele funciona
mas quando digito apenas www.dominio.com.br aparece a seguinte url

```
http://www.dominio.com.br/public/https://www.dominio.com.br
```

preciso de uma forçar para resolver isso.
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Laravel precisa ser criado uma `middleware` para força o redirecionamento da seguinte forma:

Crie na pasta `app\Http\Middleware` um arquivo com o nome de `RedirectHttps.php` e em seu contéudo:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RedirectHttps
{   
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'dev') 
        {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Lembrando que esse processo pode ser feito pela linha de comando

> `php artisan make:middleware RedirectHttps`

Após a criação do arquivo precisa ser registrado isso no arquivo `kernel.php` contido na pasta `app\Http\` adicionando uma linha da seguinte forma na configuração denominada `$middlewareGroups`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectHttps::class,     
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Essa configuração vai funcionar muito bem no servidor de produção como está no código informado (`env('APP_ENV') === 'dev'`).

Se a sua versão do Laravel for maior ou igual 5.4 (`>=5.4`) tem um método a ser invocado no `App\Providers\AppServiceProvicer.php` com o seguinte código `URL::forceScheme('https');`, exemplo:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

que auxilia na geração das `urls` do site, mas, não redireciona igual a primeira configuração, ou seja, essencial é a primeira parte da resposta. No arquivo `.htaccess` pode ser fazer uma configuração também

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

mas, o redirecionamento só funcionou usando o `middlweare` criado.

Comment: A segunda opção funcionou pra mim. Eu não entendo os riscos mas deixarei essa opção de forçar https dentro do laravel para outro dia. Muito obrigado e vou deixar um "Plus,Like" marcado em sua resposta. Valeu!